# Acoustical Design considerations for Active Noise Cancellation Project for Air vent

Tags: acoustics, signal-processing, noise

I am working on ''Active noise cancellation for air vent'' project. I am
using NI myRIO1900, Audio Technica ATR 3350 omni directional microphones
and Tevion Loudspeakers. I have done the programming using LabVIEW and I
have used FPGA module.
I am using sinusoidal noise source of (200-500 Hz) as test noise signal.

I have implemented LMS on LabVIEW, as a preliminary results I am getting
around 8dB noise reduction but these results are pretty random in a sense
only at certain volume levels( if I adjust very carefully), the noise
cancellation is happening and the variation in step size is not giving any
decent change ( again I have to make volume level changes to see some
results).

Over all, I am getting some results but I don't have control over the
results.

This is my set up
[image]
[the pipe length is 1 meter]
I know I have to consider secondary path modelling and feedback modelling.
I have actually completed the coding of FBFxLMS also but I dont have any reasonable results with this also.

But my question how to improve the acoustical design of my setup. What are
the problems using just cardboard material to simulate the environment of
air vent ??

I have read in 2-3 places that without proper acoustical design it is not
possible to reduce the noise effectively. Quoting from a paper ''**If the
acoustical design of the system is not optimized,the digital controller
may not be able to attenuate the undesired noise adequately.''**

The only point I am aware of is using low frequency noises (<= 500Hz) to
consider the sound wave propagation as plane acoustic wave. I am
completely unaware of any other details on how to better my acoustical
design.

I am wondering how to find the limitations of how much a DSP will affect and how much the actual acoustic design. If anyone can provide some reasonable resources to go through, it will be highly appreciated.

Please help me if some one has experience with ANC or Acoustical design.

Thank you.

Comment: You might get much better answers on the Engineering SE.

Comment: K I will try it over there.

Comment: This is definitely about engineering... the limitations have relatively little to do with physics, except that even the best algorithm can cancel noise in one point only, at the position of the error microphone. If the noise comes from other places of the vent as well, or bypasses the vent entirely, then nothing you do at this one position will help. In practice this kind of noise cancellation only works in well controlled environments. You can't just ship it as a DIY vent kit and hope for the best, not even with modeling of a few standard configurations.

Comment: @CuriousOne Hey, I too want to cancel the noise only at the position of  error microphone. It's not DIY project, it is my master thesis could become my PhD interest as well. The model that I was using is just prototype to demonstrate the ANC principle with basic results. Now I want to design whole new system with proper acoustical considerations and I am looking for help. Tq :)

Comment: @charansai: Sorry for the misunderstanding... I didn't mean to say that your work is DIY. I was simply referring to the problem of deploying an acoustic system without the considerations that you are involved with right now. One can buy noise canceling headphones because the human head is a pretty forgiving acoustic system, but if you were to offer your duct at the home improvement store, most people would be highly dissatisfied with the performance because their environments would be so different from your test environment that the product wouldn't work well, most of the time.

Comment: The most trivial reason why you aren't getting much improvement is because the exit of the duct is probably not the main source of the acoustic emissions that you are trying to suppress. Cardboard is an order of magnitude (or more?) less dense than the usual steel that is being used for ducts would be. I would strongly suggest to go to the store and buy some actual ducting hardware. I would also suggest to make some measurements of how much of the sound couples trough the air and how much will be conducted trough the steel... I have a feeling that you are fighting the wrong sound path.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance @CuriousOne. I will try to go for steel as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If the duct structure has passive modes that are within the bandwidth of the 'noise' you are imposing, and the active controller they can sap and release energy resulting phase shifts. Also the tube like structure whether closed or open will impose a standing wave resonance with all the possible harmonics that may be near or not near to the frequency you are trying to attenuate. The fact that volume (amplitude ) results in differereces response suggests that there is some component acting in a nonlinear fashion.

But other than these suggestions, and without additional testing, and data, it's difficult to say precisely what your problem (s) are.

Comment: His problem is the same as that of every noise cancellation setup: he wants to null a field with an effectively infinite number of degrees of freedom with a one dimensional controller.

Comment: @CuriousOne I agree nullify is a fanciful endeavor, however reducing intensity is realistic goal. Big business,  $$ made in product design.

Comment: A good book is Inverse Adaptive Control by Widow et al

Comment: You mean the headsets? They are OK, but the price you pay is mostly for the IP protection strategy of a certain company. Technologically you are being ripped off IMHO. To be very honest... it's not rocket science to build a quiet vent... you just make it a little larger, so that the Reynolds number goes down significantly, isn't it?

Comment: Thanks for the reference @docscience . Is there any practical guide available discussing acoustic design and practical problems faced in ANC ?

Comment: @charansai - sorry I don't know of any. But regarding standing waves and how placement of the microphone/speaker at nodes/antinodes, I did meet a professor and students at the Univ of Connecticut last year that have mapped stability regions for a Rijke tube - to control a thermoacoustic instability. Perhaps their work might lead you to ideas: Link: https://www.engr.uconn.edu/alarm/research?id=109